# How to turn a narrow table into a wide table

Tags: cnosdb

I want to turn a narrow table into a wide table, how should I do it?

**The original table reads:**

```
public › select * from test;
+-----------------------------+------+-------+
|  time                       | tag  | value |
+-----------------------------+------+-------+
| 12023-05-17T02:43:38.290401 | taga | 65.0  |
| 12023-05-17T02:43:38.290401 | tagb | 66.0  |
+-----------------------------+------+-------+
```

**Expected results:**

```
+-----------------------------+------+--------+------+--------+
|  time                       | taga | valuea | tagb | valueb |
+-----------------------------+------+--------+------+--------+
| 12023-05-17T02:43:38.290401 | taga | 65.0   | tagb | 66.0   |
+-----------------------------+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.